# Opening particular folder on clicking on status Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, internal-storage

I am displaying downlaoded file progress in status Notification.I want to open particular downloaded folder on clicking on notification once download is over.I used below code but it is always opening first “Open From” window and when i select “File Manager”  from window then its opening root directory of internal storage.Where am I going wrong?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Uri uri = Uri.parse(folder.getPath());
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "file/*");


 final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
                        .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Folder opens, but clicking on the file, It's not opening.
got any solution?

Comment: @RumitPatel did you solve the issue.??

Answer (score 2):

Try this might work

```
Uri pathUri= Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/blahblahfolder/");
intent.setDataAndType(pathUri, "file/*");
```

Hope this works.

Comment: same issue wid this also......whts the difference u just replaced `folder.getPath()` with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/blahblahfolder/"`?..my `folder` is   `File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "blahblah")`